# Как добавить текст после ссылки в HTML

Tags: html, wordpress, url, redirect, link

Мне нужно, чтобы после того, как кто-нибудь, например, написал цифру 20, она добавилась к ссылке.

Например, если я напишу число "20" и нажму на кнопку "ок", то меня кинет на заранее запрограммированную ссылку "test.com", но еще добавит число "20", чтобы получилось "test.com/20".

Я попытался так, но у меня не получилось:

```
<form action="test.com/">
  <input name="value" type="text" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы только на русском языке, пожалуйста переведите.

Comment: This is StackOverflow in Russian. Please translate your question or use StackOverflow en.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var srclnk = "https://google.com/";
var inp = document.getElementById("linkcreator");
var lnk = document.getElementById("link");
inp.addEventListener("input", function(){
  lnk.href = srclnk+inp.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="type the url" id="linkcreator"/><a href="https://google.com/" id="link">Go</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает)